# Is using a loop to wait more CPU-intensive in python than a sleep command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wait, sleep

On python 3 I need to stop until a certain time. And I need to be fairly precise on when I wake up. The problem is that in this pause I should do some calculations that will take part of that time. So I cannot just `time.sleep()` through it or I would start too late.

So I was thinking of running this code:

```
import time
wakeuptime=time.time()+20 #start again exactly 20 seconds from now
UnpredictablySlowFunction()  
while (time.time()<wakeuptime): 
    pass
```

I am a bit worried that this kind of loop might be more uselessly CPU-intensive than a normal `time.sleep()`. Especially considering the program should run in the background 24/7.

Comment: First do the calculations, then see how much time remains and sleep that amount?

Comment: thanks, but that would not work. I simplified here, but I have several functions I need to call, and I change the code fairly often.

Comment: Even putting `time.sleep(1)` in the body of the loop would be a vast improvement over `pass`, as Python could check the condition a *lot* in one second.

Comment: sorry, @tobias_k I did not understand your suggestion until running.t spelled it out

Comment: @chepner one second delay is also a lot! A lot of things happen in one second ;-). But I believe the solution from "running.t" (below) would work fine

Comment: My point was that you can sleep for whatever tolerance you have for starting late, and it will almost certainly be significantly better than a pure busy-wait.

Comment: On my laptop, I was able to call `time.time` ~7.2 million times in 5 seconds. Even `time.sleep(0.01)` cuts that down to ~400, and `time.time()` is probably only accurate to a hundredth of a second anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @tobias_k mentioned in comment, try this:

```
import time
wakeuptime=time.time()+20 #start again exactly 20 seconds from now
UnpredictablySlowFunction()  
time_left = wakeuptime -time.time()
time.sleep(time_left)
```

Comment: nice one, simple and elegant. LOL

Comment: Be sure `time_left` is positive before calling `time.sleep`, though.

Comment: Or just do `try: time.sleep(...) except: pass` :)

Comment: it's unfortunate time.sleep(-t) doesn't permit me to go back in time for t seconds :-( ;-)